# How to know if an associative array has the same value for all the recurrence?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array like this:

```
9584=>string
5324=>string
6543=>string
```

The key is always a number but I assign it dynamically so I don't know the numbers and probably they are not consecutive.

I need to know if the string is the same in ALL of the occurrence in the array.

If you can help me thank you... and sorry for my horrible English

Comment: um.. how about foreach?

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will return only one result

Comment: Thank you Mark!... just the thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me count the ways...  There are bound to be more:

```
if(count(array_flip($array)) === 1) { }

if(count(array_unique($array)) === 1) { }

if(count(array_count_values($array)) === 1) { }
```

Comment: What about it?  Time these and your loop and post the results so we will know.

Answer (score 0):

Read the first value and browse your array until you find a different one.

```
<?php
function allTheSame($array)
{
    if (count($array) != 0)
    {
        $first = reset($array);
        foreach($array => $v)
        {
            if ($v !== $first)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```